# Can carbocation rearrangements have kinetic and thermodynamic products?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reaction-control

As the figure in this [webpage](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/tips/kinetic-thermodynamic/) says, at low temperatures, the major product of hydrohalogenation of 1,3-butadiene is the kinetic product, the 1,2-addition product. At high temperatures, the major product is the thermodynamic product, the 1,4-addition product, in which the pi electrons have transferred to the inner carbon skeleton to form a more substituted alkene product. **The carbocation rearranged due to resonance.**

However, as the figure below from David Klein's Organic Chemistry 2e book tells us--the major hydrohalogenation product of 3-methyl-1-butene is the rearrangement product, which is the more stable product. **Here, the carbocation rearranged due to its inherent stability at highly substituted carbons.** The temperature of the reaction was not specified.

[image: hydrochlorination of 3-methyl-1-butene]

**My questions are:**

- Is it safe to assume that the hydrochlorination of 3-methyl-1-butene give a product ratio as shown in the figure at all temperatures (except at temperatures where decomposition may occur, if it can)?
- Do alkene addition reactions also have thermodynamic and kinetic control, like the butadiene reaction exhibited, or is the thermo and kinetic product production only due to resonance?
- Can carbocation rearrangements have kinetic and thermodynamic products, like the one for the hydrohalogenation of butadiene?

Comment: These are fundamentally different. Resonance isn't a "rearrangement".

Comment: Confused by title. Being under thermodynamic control implies not being under kinetic control.